# Store App names in NSArray from JSON DATA which Stored in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, api, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have retrive following response form Server in `JSON` format which I have sucessfully store in `NSDictionary`.

```
{
    "@companyName" = "MobileAPPSDeveloper";
    "@generatedDate" = "8/6/13 2:41 AM";
    "@version" = "1.0";
    application =     (

            {
        "@apiKey" = 234FXPQB36GHFF2334H;
        "@createdDate" = "2013-03-01";
        "@name" = FirstApp;
        "@platform" = iPhone;
    },
            {
        "@apiKey" = 3PF9WDY234546234M3Z;
        "@createdDate" = "2013-02-01";
        "@name" = SecondAPP;
        "@platform" = iPhone;
    },
            {
        "@apiKey" = NXGQXM2347Y23234Q4;
        "@createdDate" = "2013-05-22";
        "@name" = ThirdApp;
        "@platform" = Android;
    }
);

}
```

This is method I have used.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self convertDataIntoDictionary:responseData];
}

-(void)convertDataIntoDictionary:(NSData*)data{
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    if (data.length>0) {
        NSError *parsingDataError;
        dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parsingDataError];

        if (parsingDataError) {
            //            [ErrorAlert showError:parsingDataError];
            NSString *recievedString = [[NSString  alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Data Conversion Error When Parsing: %@", recievedString);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Data back from server\n %@",dictionary);
    NSArray *applicationDetails = dictionary[@"application"];

}
```

I can not go further then this?

I would like to get All NAME of APPS in Array.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of parsing JSON is:

> { }- dis represents dictionary
>   ( )- dis represents array

So in your `JSON`, there is a `dictionary` at the root and inside it has a key `application` which cbntains an `Array`.

```
NSArray *applicationArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"application"];
NSMutableArray *mutableAppNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Inside this array there are three `NSDictionary` at every index:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in applicationArray){
  NSString *appName = [dict objectForKey:@"@name"];
  NSLog(@"app name : %@", appName);
  [mutableAppNamesArray addObject:appName];
}

NSArray * appNamesArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableAppNamesArray];
```

Comment: Hi Puneet Thanks for answer!! I will keep that in mind and try to convert data accordingly. will let update in few mins!!

Comment: NSArray *appNamesArray = [[NSArray alloc]init]; NSArray does not have addobject: method!! And if I change to NSMutableArray it give me Error[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am not using IDE. I have edited. Use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray. If you would need NSArray, you can create it from NSMutableArray.

Comment: Finally got an answer!! I have also edited answer!! thanks Puneet

Comment: Glad it worked. I have included your edit in the final answer. Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a proper format for JSON. JSON objects usually contain ':' instead of '='

Example :-

```
{
products_id: "476",
products_model: "XOLO Play",
products_price: "15499.0000",
products_image: "xolo-play-play-t1000-.jpg",
products_date_available: null,
products_last_modified: "2013-08-04 06:04:11",
products_date_added: "2013-08-04 06:03:10",
manufacturers_id: "17",
products_status: "1",
products_rating: null,
category_id: "11"
},
{
products_id: "18",
products_model: "Nokia Lumia 820",
products_price: "8990.0000",
products_image: "samsung-galaxy-ace-duos-gsm-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg",
products_date_available: null,
products_last_modified: "2013-07-30 03:45:28",
products_date_added: "2013-01-23 00:52:00",
manufacturers_id: "2",
products_status: "1",
products_rating: "3",
category_id: "11"
},
```

But if you still need to parse it then you might try as below:

First get into the array 
 by  `NSDictionary *array = [allValues objectForKey:@"application"];` then each index to NSDictionary and then object for key. If its your server response than try to make it in the proper JSON format.

Comment: Actual server response is : not =

Comment: Than @Puneet ans will sure help you :)